# select only the column from one table with the column name that matches the value of a row in another table

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I am trying to select only the column from one table with the column name that matches the value of a row in another table. I've done a series of joins and this is the last join that I've matched based on one criteria.
In this case I would only want the column 'GRAIN' from the b. table

I've attempted a column from statement and a couple of case when's, but I'm not sure If I should somehow list all the column names from table b
left join [dbo].[FALC] as b on e.[ST] = b.[ST]

left join [dbo].[FALC] as b on e.[ST] = b.[ST][enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfBq3.png)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Tag with your DBMS. [ask] [mcve] Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations.

Comment: Using values for columns is pivoting. Read about querying tables with values as columns via hardwiring column names in queries or more generally by either writing dynamic SQL and/or using the PIVOT command of some DBMSs. PS From this & other recent questions of yours, you have input tables that have been prematurely pivoted. Pivoting values into columns should happen last for display to users & should usually be done via a GUI. Whenever possible use input that has values in rows not as columns. Otherwise you just have to undo the pivoting that created an input in order to use it easily.

Comment: ... Eg: Suppose we have SQL table (a, b, f_of_ab). We could *display* it via a *display table* with 3 columns or we could pivot it to a *display table* with an a axis down the page/rows & b axis across the page/columns & entries that are f_of_ab(a,b) when defined/present but otherwise a blank or null. But an SQL table (a, b1, ...) that looks like the pivoted display table is *not good for further querying*, you should use the former SQL table.